# Is there a usable Namecoin GUI client?

Tags: client, namecoin

Is there any GUI client that is capable of trading Namecoin, and is somewhat trusted by the community?

Comment: it's no longer available, I realize that this is a very old question,

Answer (score 5):

[Multicoin](http://www.multicoin.net/) can be used to trade Namecoin although the functions for registering names and such cannot be used.

There is a current bounty of 750NMC to produce a web UI for the client to run within a local machine. It can be found on the http://dot-bit.org wiki site.

Comment: Do you know Where can I find a Windows binary of MultiCoin?http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1421/where-can-i-find-a-windows-binary-of-multicoin

Answer (score 3):

[A .Net NameCoin GUI](http://www.reddit.com/r/namecoingui/comments/l817u/namecoingui/) was recently posted to Reddit.

Comment: Testing in a VM now. If this works it's some of the most fantastic news for NameCoin I've heard in a while.

Comment: @DavidPerry - do post your test results, please.

Comment: on my XP test VM it works quite well and at least hasn't made a grab for `%appdata%\roaming\Bitcoin\wallet.dat` or sent/received anything other than standard Bitcoin traffic. It's closed-source so I'm not sure how much I trust it, but it seems to be working and hasn't done anything malicious yet.

Comment: it's no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is a very old question, but I think it makes sense to give an update nevertheless.  Recently, a port of the Qt-UI for Bitcoin has been done also for Namecoin.  It provides full support also for name operations and even configuring domains directly without the need to come up with the correct JSON strings.

The new Namecoin-Qt is available at https://github.com/namecoin-qt/namecoin-qt, and third-party binaries can be found at https://namecoin.org/download.