# Where can I find a Windows binary of MultiCoin?

Tags: namecoin

MultiCoin is AFAIK the only GUI client that supports [NameCoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Namecoin). Is there a trusted Windows binary to be found?

Comment: I'd gladly use one of your Windows builds if you had them online anywhere.

Comment: @JerodC.Batte - "your"? I am not affiliated with MultiCoin, nor do I have a build.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing windows builds of multicoin-exp, but have not heard of anyone using them so don't keep it up to date unless I get a request usually.

http://www.wuala.com/jbw9/pub/Bitcoin/multicoin/MultiCoin-exp/src/bitcoin.exe/ is actually mutlicoin, however I am pretty sure this version only works with the config file that would have been compatible with .62 and needs to be updated for .63 now that we have passed block 19200.  I can update it if anyone wants it to be.

Comment: Thanks. If any recognized forum members vouched for @twobits, that would increase my confidence in this exe, as I don't know him myself.